# AJAX returns different values for same parameters

Tags: jquery, ajax, iis, model-view-controller, datatables

I'm running into a very strange issue in my MVC application.

I've deployed an application on an IIS environment (IIS v8.5.9600.16384) , that uses a standard jQuery DataTable. The parameters passed are directly plugged to the controller side methods and class functions, to fetch data from an SQL Server.

It works just fine when the number of users concurrently using it is low. But, when the number of users increases, I start seeing erratic data when I call an AJAX reload of the table in question - that's either filtered out, or nothing at all - even though my jQuery DataTable, parameters passed (checked from the console), and data in the SQL table are unchanged.

So, if the number of rows is supposed to be 200, it shows 200 rows in multiple pages when there's reduced server activity or the application is hosted on a clone environment. But, when the activity increases, the row count varies greatly (any random number that isn't 200, sometimes even 0) for the same input parameters.

This is what my DataTable looks like:

```
 $('#tblGrid').DataTable({
            "createdRow": function (row, data, dataIndex) {
                 if (data.Incomplete == "Yes") {
                        $(row).css("color", "blue");
                    }
            },
            "scrollY": tableHeight,
            "iDisplayLength": displayLength,
            "fnDrawCallback": function () {
                var rowCount = $('#tblGrid tr').length;
                if (rowCount < displayLength) {
                    $('#divtblGrid').height(Math.floor((displayLength * 30) + 90));
                }
                else {
                    $('#divtblGrid').height("2%");
                }
            },
            "ajax": {
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                "url": '<%=Url.Action("ShowRecord","FrontOffice")%>',
                "dataSrc": function (json) {
                    if (json == "SessionExpired") {
                        location.href = '<%=Url.Action("LoginStart","Login")%>';
                    }
                    else {
                        return (JSON.parse(json));
                    }
                },
                "type": "POST",
                "contentType": "application/json",
                "data": function () {
                    return JSON.stringify({
                        "FromDate": $('#FromDate').val(),
                        "ToDate": $('#ToDate').val(),
                        "Department": $('#ddService').val()
                    })
                }
            },
            initComplete: function () {
                bindGridEvent();
                if (selectedRowName != undefined && $("#tblGrid").DataTable().row(selectedRow).node() != undefined) {
                    if ($("#tblGrid").DataTable().row(selectedRow).data().Name == selectedRowName) {
                        $("#tblGrid").DataTable().row(selectedRow).node().click();
                    }
                    else {
                        $("#tblGrid").DataTable().state.clear()
                        $("#tblGrid").DataTable().ajax.reload();
                    }
                }
            },
            "aoColumnDefs":
            [
               { "mData": "SNo", "aTargets": [0], "bSearchable": false, "sTitle": "SrNo" },                  
               { "mData": "Name", "aTargets": [1], "sTitle": "Name" },
               { "mData": "Age/Sex", "aTargets": [2], "sTitle": "Age/Gender" },
               { "mData": "MobileNo", "aTargets": [3], "sTitle": "Mobile No"},
               { "mData": "Incomplete", "aTargets": [4], "sTitle": "Incomplete"}
           ],
            stateSave: true,
            "stateDuration": 0,
            "stateSaveParams": function (settings, data) {
                data.FromDate = $("#FromDate").val();
                data.ToDate = $("#ToDate").val();
                data.Department = $('#ddService').val();
                if ($("tr.active").length > 0) {
                    data.selectedRow = $("#tblGrid").DataTable().row($("tr.active")).index();
                    data.selectedRowName = $("#tblGrid").DataTable().row($("tr.active")).data().Name;
                }
            },
            "stateLoadParams": function (settings, data) {
                $("#FromDate").val(data.FromDate);
                $("#ToDate").val(data.ToDate);
                data.Department = $('#ddService').val();
                selectedRow = data.selectedRow;
                selectedRowName = data.selectedRowName;
            }
        });
    });
```

This is what my controller side method looks like:

```
public JsonResult ShowRecord(string FromDate, string ToDate, string Department)
    {
        Employees objEmp = new Employees();
        DataTable dtGrid = objEmp.mShowRecords(FromDate, ToDate, Department);
        return Json(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dtGrid, Formatting.None), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

And this is what my class looks like:

```
Public Function mShowRecords(ByVal sFromDate As String, ByVal sToDate As String, ByVal Department As String) As DataTable
            Dim sqlParam() As SqlParameter
            Dim dt As DataTable = Nothing
            ReDim sqlParam(3)
            sqlParam(0) = New SqlParameter("@FromDate", SqlDbType.VarChar)
            sqlParam(0).Value = GetDBDate(sFromDate)
            sqlParam(1) = New SqlParameter("@ToDate", SqlDbType.VarChar)
            sqlParam(1).Value = GetDBDate(sToDate)
            sqlParam(2) = New SqlParameter("@LoginName", SqlDbType.VarChar)
            sqlParam(2).Value = LoginUserDetails.LoginName
            sqlParam(3) = New SqlParameter("@Department", SqlDbType.SmallInt)
            If Department = "" Then
                sqlParam(3).Value = 0
            Else
                sqlParam(3).Value = Convert.ToInt16(Department)
            End If

            mShowRecords = ExecuteStoreProcDataTable("[sp_ShowEmployeeData]", sqlParam)
        End Function
```

(LoginUserDetails is a struct that stores user specific information when they log in to the application from their browsers. It's used in the stored procedure to check the authentication level of the logged in user.)

I'm unable to figure out if there's something I should check on the IIS (it's running the default settings, with the limits unchanged), since the same application works fine when there's no activity, or it is hosted on a second, dummy application that's connected to the same database and uses the same files. I've cleared the cache multiple times, and it works fine once or twice, after which is throws random values yet again.

I'd appreciate help in this regard, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This issue might relate to your SQL statement in the stored procedure. Such as Row_Number is used instead of Count(*) as the way calculating the entries. Most of the cases relate to SQL command . Have a look at these links.
[select query returns different results for the same query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51218099/select-query-returns-different-results-for-the-same-query)
[SQL Server/DB2: Same query returns different results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952203/sql-server-db2-same-query-returns-different-results)
[Same query giving different results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50162123/same-query-giving-different-results)

Comment: Thank you! I checked my code, and it turns out that the problem was being caused because of the Struct (that passed the login name) and the procedure (which checked authentication for the login name). The struct was being reset elsewhere, when a different user logged in. Replacing it with Session Variables did the trick for me!